# NSPredicate - How to check if every parent has visible == true

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

my coredata structure contains "folder"s. Every folder can have a parent folder which can have a parent folder which can have a parent folder and so on. Folder can also have entities called "item". Folder has also property called "visible".

I want to retrieve all "item"s whose folder (and every parent folder if there is) has visible == true. How I can make this kind of NSPredicate?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392587/help-with-coredata-making-a-nspredicate-recursive-searching