# Keypath <transientproperty> not found in entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I want to show a formatted date in the section header of a table view..

I used the following code.but its throwing an exception `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath dateSectionIdentifier not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Expense id=1>'`.

guess the exception is coming when adding a sort descriptor.

```
NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
NSSortDescriptor *mainSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:dateSectionIdentifier ascending:NO];
[sortDescriptors addObject:mainSortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

//Expense.h

```
NSString *dateSectionIdentifier;
```

//Expense.m

```
@dynamic dateSectionIdentifier

-(NSString *)dateSectionIdentifier{
[self willAccessValueForKey:@"dateSectionIdentifier"];
NSString *tempDate = [self primitiveDateSectionIdentifier];
[self didAccessValueForKey:@"dateSectionIdentifier"];
if(!tempDate){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
    tempDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self date]];
    [self setPrimitiveDateSectionIdentifier:tempDate];
    [dateFormatter release];
}
return tempDate;

}
```

Comment: Show us the declaration and initialization of `dateSectionIdentifier`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The title of your question indicates that "dateSectionIdentifier" is a *transient* property.

You cannot use a transient property in a sort descriptor (or in a predicate) of a Core Data fetch request if SQLite is used as store type. That is a documented restriction, only persistent properties can be used.

See [Persistent Store Types and Behaviors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html) in the "Core Data Programming Guide"
for more information.

Comment: the link is broken ;(

Comment: @Oriol: Thanks for the notice, I have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have added "dateSectionIdentifier" in the subclass, but not updated in the .xcdatamodelId file.
Cross check to see whether you have added "dateSectionIdentifier" in .xcdatamodelId file or not.