# Core Data recursive search using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a project using Core Data with "folder" and "document" entities. A folder can contain many documents, and also other folders.

I'm working on a search feature, and in the current version I have something like this which finds documents/folders within a particular folder that have a name that partially matches the search text:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == %@ AND name CONTAINS[cd] %@", folderToSearch, searchText)
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

However, I'd like it to also search within folders that are children of the current one (and if it finds a match, include the containing folder in the results).

For example, if my folder/document structure was like this (assume the Shopping folder and Travel folder are contained within the same parent folder):

```
Shopping
    Groceries
        - toothpaste
        - cheese
Travel
    Packing
        - toothpaste
        - toothbrush
```

... and I searched for "toothpaste", I'd want the search to return the "Shopping" folder object and the "Travel" folder object.

What I need is something like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == %@ AND name (OR ANY OF IT'S CHILDREN'S NAMES) CONTAINS[cd] %@", folderToSearch, searchText)
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Is there any way to form an NSPredicate to do what I want?

Or something else I should consider doing?

---

UPDATE: Yes, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392587/help-with-coredata-making-a-nspredicate-recursive-searching) to this already. However, the accepted answer there suggests using a "transient boolean property" and using that in the NSPredicate... but everything else I've read says that won't work when using an SQLite store. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972685/234609) and [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/237109-only-one-reason-to-ever-use-transient-properties-in-core-data.html).) So I think my question is still valid. I've also updated my question to clarify exactly what I need.

Note that when I first posted this question, I incorrectly thought about adding a transient property to determine if a document/folder is a child/grandchild/etc. of the folder that the search started from, and changed the predicate to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDescendentOfSearchParent == YES AND name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

... but quickly learned that [transient properties don't work in NSPredicates when used with an SQLite store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972685/234609). (Plus, this would return the document/folder that matched the search text, not its containing folder... which isn't what I want.)

Comment: @alex-kosyakov The accepted answer on that question suggests using a "transient boolean property" and using that in the NSPredicate, but everything else I've read, including the [response I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15972685/234609) in my post, says that's not possible when using an SQLite store.  See also: ["you cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties"](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/237109-only-one-reason-to-ever-use-transient-properties-in-core-data.html).  (I will edit my question later today to clarify)

Comment: One of solution is to set some parent id to your subfolders, that will be == id of main folder and search all subfolders with predicate parentID == %@